# Save/backup Ubuntu server with users and state over SSH to image or similar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, iso-image, system-restore

I have a remote Ubuntu server which I will install a small software stack on, set up one user, configure the firewall, and change a few systems setting on.

After I have done that I would like to back the state up to an image or back the server up in some other way so that I can restore it on an other Ubuntu server. It need to retain the stack, firewall, user, etc.

Is this possible and what would be the best way to do this over SSH

Comment: Maybe the better solution is to use *Infrastructure as Code* tools like Terraform, cloud-init, Ansible and the like.

Comment: @DanielB remember this is not Server Fault - there is nothing wrong with this in concept - and it can be a lot faster to set up if its not going to be done at scale.

Comment: Have you considered buildinng a docker image instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to take this approach, if possible set up the system in a VM.  Then suspend (or better shut down) thr instance and clone the backing device. This is the easiest and most reliable way.

(I started going through how to do it manually, and realised there are a lot of gotchas because you have to navigate arround backing up a live filesystem (it can be done using lvm snapshots for example, or by abusing mdadm and degrading the disk, but neither of these solutions are "nice".  Its likely also possible you can make a 3 partition install, clone (boot, root and temproot), then once you have set up boot and root pivot to temproot, make root and boot readonly and take your backup but all these are horribly messy and error prone - you would likely be better off followong a tutorial to recreate a bootable system at the file level rather then image level - eg using something like https://github.com/AB9IL/linux-clone)

Answer (score 0):

The general approach:

```
echo "password-for-sudo" | ssh remote@server.name sudo -S tar --one-file-system -cpf - / > /tmp/server.tar
```

Don't worry that something changes during this operation. If you care, stop all the services you can (e.g. databases, web servers, etc.); everything else doesn't matter.

`sudo -S` reads password from the stdin, `echo` puts it to the stdin of `ssh` which in turn streams it to the remotely executed `sudo`. It runs on the remote `tar --one-file-system -cpf - /` (as root), which archives everything and streams that into stdout. The `ssh` streams stdout back to the localhost, where `> /tmp/server.tar` writes it into the file. You can chain e.g. `gzip` locally to immediately compress a file, and also add a compression option to `ssh` speed up transfer, if it's going via Internet.

To avoid having password in the command line, you may create a file, put it inside and cat that file into ssh stdin instead of echo.

The `--one-file-system` option is used to not to capture `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys` and so on. If there *are* some mounted file systems you want to capture, add them after `/`, like this: `tar --one-file-system -cpf - / /boot /home`. Other way to get around virtual file systems is to create a bind-mount of / and take it:

```
mkdir /tmp/root-bind
mount -o bind / /tmp/root-bind
mount -o bind /home /tmp/root-bind/home
...
```

Now, use something like `... ssh ... sudo ... tar -cpf - /tmp/root-bind > ...`. Don't forget to unmount everything afterwards. Or, at last, you can use `tar` *excludes* to achieve the same effect.

---

A variant of this streaming approach uses `netcat` and SSH TCP forwarding. E.g. you start `ssh -R rport:localhost:lport`, and run netcat locally listening on that lport and writing to a file. Then, on the remote, you either bind-mount or otherwise exclude non-needed directories and `tar` stream goes to another (remote) `netcat` which writes to "localhost" rport (which ssh forwards to lport on the local).

Comment: How does this handle grub/bootable image creation? This seems good for backup, but not to have a "ready-to-boot" image.

Comment: So, after unpacking just chroot and grub-install.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I would love to be wrong but would have thought there would be more to this - for a start handling different partition layouts and different device UUID's of the filesystem.  I hope im overthinking things but dont you need to use something like dracut to recreate the initrd to take into account niggles like this? Also  how do you take this file-level copy and trear it as an image - presumably there are steps you need to take to create it inside a virtual partitioned disk.

Comment: You are right, depending on a circumstances you might need to update fstab, recreate grub config or even intramfs, but all of these are easy single-command steps to do once you're in the chroot. Notice there was *no* requirement to have a *disk* image, only the *system* image (honestly, using disk images just to clone Linux is overkill). The o.p. asked for "some other way"; this way is most easy with SSH, it's a single liner and only involves s/w already installed. Actually it fits for any distro, not just Ubuntu. And yes, being a Gentoo user since around 2004, I done such things many times.